# How do I keep all values from LEFT OUTER JOIN table when using SUM as one of the retrieved tables, and why does GROUP BY seem to fix the issue?

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull information from 2 very small tables of customers and their purchase information. The two tables are "customers" with id, name, email. And "orders" with id, customer_id, item, price.

The output I want is to have the customer name, email, and the total of all of their lifetime purchases.

The problem is that there are some customers who have never purchased anything or only made one purchase. So even after using LEFT OUTER JOIN to merge the tables and include each customer, I only get information on customers who have made more than one purchase (when the SUM function can work).

This seems to be resolved when I choose to GROUP BY customers.name. I have no clue why this actually works though and would like to know how this interaction between LEFT OUTER JOIN, SUM, and GROUP BY works. Below is the entire table of information and everything I am trying to do to pull the information.

GROUP BY seems to fix the problem, but I would like to know why it is actually working.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT);

INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Doctor Who", "doctorwho@timelords.com");
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Harry Potter", "harry@potter.com");
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Captain Awesome", "captain@awesome.com");

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    customer_id INTEGER,
    item TEXT,
    price REAL);

INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price)
    VALUES (1, "Sonic Screwdriver", 1000.00);
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price)
    VALUES (2, "High Quality Broomstick", 40.00);
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price)
    VALUES (1, "TARDIS", 1000000.00);

SELECT customers.name, customers.email, SUM(orders.price) AS total
FROM customers LEFT OUTER JOIN
     orders
     ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.name 
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` is not syntactically correct because `customers.email` is not in the `GROUP BY` and `customers.name` is not a primary or unique key.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are using MySQL -- and an older version at that, because the default settings in the newer version would give you a syntax error.

If you attempt this query

```
SELECT c.name, c.email, SUM(o.price) AS total
FROM customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

You have a bastardized SQL query.  The query:

- is an aggregation query (because of the `SUM()`);
- returns one row (because there is no `GROUP BY`);
- has two lingering columns, `c.name` and `c.email`.

Most databases (properly) reject such a query.  MySQL happens to allow it (in older versions).  The values of `c.name` and `c.email` come from *arbitrary* rows.  The `SUM()` is the sum over all the data.

The proper way to phrase this is as:

```
SELECT c.name, c.email, SUM(o.price) AS total
FROM customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.name, c.email
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` contains the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  This produces one row for each customer name/email.

Because `customers.id` is a primary key, you can also write this as:

```
SELECT c.name, c.email, SUM(o.price) AS total
FROM customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```